# How can I write this urllize function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

I know this issue has been discussed numerous times, but I think this is the solution best for me:

Given a string of text, if there is a an occurance of "www.blah.com", then wrap it with `<a href="http://www.blah.com">`

How can I do that in Javascript?

Also, if there is an occurance of "http://www.blah.com", do the same thing (but do not add an extra "http://")

Comment: Read about regular expressions, they are designed for that kind of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at open-source solutions such as Linkify:

- https://github.com/maranomynet/linkify

Here is sample how to do it:

```
jQuery('body').linkify({

          handleLinks: function (links) {
              links
                  .css('background', '#ff0')
                  .after(function (i) { return ' (link '+(i+1)+')'; });
            }

        });
```

Comment: How do I turn it into target="_blank"?

Comment: I think you can add .attr("target","_blank") before .css("background","#ff0")!